No persistable permission grants found for UID
I am trying to resolve the issue of this error: No persistable permission grants found for UID
It is occurring when I am trying use contentResolver on a URI that I'm retrieving and just started yesterday whereas before there was no issue with it for months.
I would this question asked but I'm still not certain how to resolve my particular case.
ContentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission: SecurityException No persistable permission grants found for UID 10434 and Uri content:/
Commonware was able to assist them with their problem.
I have tried implementing that solution but it didn't work for me resulting in the same error again. So this is the code I have that I'm trying to work on currently.
val pickMediaOne =                         rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->                             if (uri != null) {                                 // Grant read URI permission to access the selected URI                                 val flag = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION                                 context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, flag)                                 var durationInSeconds: Int                                 try {                                     val mp: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri)                                     durationInSeconds = mp.duration / 1000                                     mp.release()                                 } catch (e: Exception) {                                     durationInSeconds = 0                                 }                                 if (durationInSeconds > 15) {                                     durationIsTooLongForMedia = true                                     snackbarMessage =                                         "Please choose a video no longer than 15 seconds."                                     scope.launch {                                         snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(                                             snackbarMessage, duration = SnackbarDuration.Short                                         )                                     }                                     //Video is too long, handle accordingly (e.g., show error message)                                 } else {                                     mediaOneState = uri.toString()                                 }                             }                         }

Only ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument and the other SAF actions are documented to offer persistable permission grants. I would not assume that ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia will offer them on all devices.
